# Trigger when condition is not equal to

Tags: wpf, styles

I need a `Style` under WPF that sets several properties when multiple conditions are fullfilled. However, one of my conditions is of type `Not Equal To`. How should I change the below `Style` so that the condition would become `Not Equal To`? Can it be even achieved without `IValueConverter`?

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <!--<Condition 1 here.../>-->
                  <!--<Condition 2 here.../>-->
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Value="3"/>
             </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
         </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I would need the below but this of course don't work since Triggers only support `Equal` operator.

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <!--<Condition 1 here.../>-->
                  <!--<Condition 2 here.../>-->
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Value<>"3"/>
             </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
         </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: *Can it be even achieved without IValueConverter?*... no it can't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need an `IValueConverter` and some extra markup for this:

```
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <!--<Condition 1 here.../>-->
                    <!--<Condition 2 here.../>-->
                    <Condition>
                        <Condition.Binding>
                            <Binding Path="id" Converter="{StaticResource ValueToEqualsParameterConverter}">
                                <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    <System:Int32>3</System:Int32>
                                </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                            </Binding>
                        </Condition.Binding>
                        <Condition.Value>
                            <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
                        </Condition.Value>
                    </Condition>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And the converter:

```
public class ValueToEqualsParameterConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { 
        return value == parameter; 
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for Enum parameter and maybe other types, it will not work. Use `return Equals(value, parameter);` in your converter instead

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to define default value as setter in style and then implement data trigger. In following code, the background value is always red except when value is 3

```html
<Style>  
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <!--<Condition 1 here.../>-->
                  <!--<Condition 2 here.../>-->
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Value="3"/>
             </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="DefaultColor"/>
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DefaultColor2"/>
         </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```