# Animated watermark in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I need to reproduce something like this [contact form](http://hyderabad.c-sharpcorner.com/): they implemented what I am expecting.

Here another sample: from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0EJr.jpg to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmAh.jpg

Comment: Elaborate a little bit... if you can create an mockup...

Comment: thanks for the reply ..updated with a link ..pls do check

Comment: So, is "name" just a kind of placeholder or a label related to the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

After you comment, I see that maybe you need something like this:

```
<TextBox Tag="Name" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1" BorderBrush="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="10" Padding="2" Foreground="Blue">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Focusable="False" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" 
                                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                                Background="#00FFFFFF" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="true" />
                                    <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Converter="{StaticResource ValueToEqualsParameterConverter}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <DataTrigger.Value>
                                    <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                </DataTrigger.Value>
                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                                </DataTrigger.Setters>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

In this case you have to use a style to create your own [template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx). You can find the `ValueToEqualsParameterConverter` implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057670/4377809).

Comment: working ,but cant see the name of the text and content

Comment: I'm sorry @rajsharmashanmugam, it is not really easy to understand your requirements by reading your question or by looking at the links. Probably you should provide more details

Comment: let me explain ,open the photo 1 in new tab and see, if you click in photo1 the "Name" should move up and allow the user to enter the details in textbox ,like photo2

Comment: problem is that ,after the text being entered in the textbox ,if you click in another textbox the "tag name" and entered content get collided.

Comment: I see your point of you @rajsharmashanmugam: just give a look to my new edit.

Comment: sorry its saying that it not suits for wpf project

Comment: better you please see this link http://hyderabad.c-sharpcorner.com/ at last there is contact us part...they implemented what i'm expecting