# Changing background of DataGridTextColumn if value is between a and b

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

So I'm trying to change the background of a cell in Datagrid depending on its value. So if i would want to change it depending on a static value i would use a StyleTrigger but that's not the case.

For example: I want a green background if the value of the cell is between 80 and 100, an orange background if the value is between 40 and 79 and a red background if it's below 40... How would i accomplish that?

Currently I'm using a StyleTrigger just for testing so don't mind that...

Here's my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Background="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Properties}, Path=TableData}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Batterie" Binding="{Binding Battery}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="83">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Current Use" Binding="{Binding CurrentUse}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Occupancy" Binding="{Binding Occupancy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057670/9285072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with writing a Converter which implements from IValueConverter interface.

if you wanna see your converter in XAML you need to reference it to a static resource like that

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:myConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

My Design;

```
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgList" Background="LightGray" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Batterie" Binding="{Binding Battery}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Battery, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Current Use" Binding="{Binding CurrentUse}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Occupancy" Binding="{Binding Occupancy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**This Binding takes your data Battery(10,30,40,80, etc.) and sends to converter.The converter returns an object and our object have to be a SolidColorBrush to bind it for BackGround.That's all.I solved like that**

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Battery, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"></Setter>
```

myConverter for Converting data to background;

```
public class myConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush clr;
        if (int.Parse(value.ToString()) >= 80)
            clr = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        else if (int.Parse(value.ToString()) >= 40)
            clr = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        else if (int.Parse(value.ToString()) >= 0)
            clr = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
            clr = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        return clr;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I created a class for your example(i did not see yours if i am wrong sorry)

```
public class Class1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }       
    public string Battery { get; set; }
    public string CurrentUse { get; set; }
    public string Occupancy { get; set; }

    public static List<Class1> myList = new List<Class1>()
    {
        new Class1() {ID = 1, Battery = "70", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 2, Battery = "100", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 3, Battery = "10", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 4, Battery = "50", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 5, Battery = "80", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 6, Battery = "40", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" },
        new Class1() {ID = 7, Battery = "39", CurrentUse = "xxxx", Occupancy = "xxxx" }
    };
}
```

On MainWindow

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dgList.ItemsSource = Class1.myList;
}
```

My Screenshots from project.

[image]

[image]